# aspnet_compiler.exe reporting errors in non-existant temporary files

Tags: asp.net

I am using `aspnet_compiler.exe` to compile my site, but it's showing errors in files that are in the `Temporary ASP.NET Files` folder.  What's more, those files do not even exist when I look for them!  How can I find out where the error is coming from?

Here are the errors:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ktbs.web\373f9415\a2aa4853\App_Web_j3jw3anh.17.cs(506, 0): error CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ktbs.web\373f9415\a2aa4853\App_Web_j3jw3anh.17.cs(512, 0): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ktbs.web\373f9415\a2aa4853\App_Web_j3jw3anh.17.cs(505, 0): error CS0106: The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item
```

Comment: Did you do a clean rebuilt, did it happen again then?

Comment: yes i did a fresh checkout from source control, deleted the temporary asp.net files and it still hapenned